# C++ void* any type implementation returns weird result

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a basic `any` type implementation in C++ (`object`), yet it always prints `CCCCCCCC` if I want to get the value from any type, and it is confusing me why (although I do know `void*`s are dangerous):

```
#include <typeinfo>
struct object
{
private:
    template < typename T > struct _base
    {
        typedef T _ptr_type;
        _ptr_type* _ptr_val()
        {
            return _ptr;
        }
        _base(_ptr_type value) : _ptr(&value){}
        _base() : _ptr(nullptr){}
        _ptr_type* _ptr;
    };
    struct _holder : _base<void*>
    {
        template < typename Ty > void cast(const _base<Ty>* p_base)
        {
            _ptr->~_ptr_type();
            _ptr_type _n_type = (_ptr_type)p_base->_ptr, *_n_ptr = &_n_type;
            std::swap<_ptr_type*>(_ptr, _n_ptr);
        }
        _holder(){}
    };
public:
    _holder* _h_ptr;
    object() : _h_ptr(new _holder){}
    template < typename T > object(const T& value) : _h_ptr(new _holder)
    {
        _base<T> _t_base(value);
        _h_ptr->cast(&_t_base);
    }
    template < typename T > void operator=(const T& value)
    {
        _base<T> _t_base(value);
        _h_ptr->cast(&_t_base);
    }
    const void* operator()() const
    {
        return *_h_ptr->_ptr_val();
    }
};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    object MyObject = 'c';
    std::cout << MyObject();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I suspect busted alignment.  Building an `any` type class from scratch is a significant challenge.  Valuable as an educational exploration, but I hope you're not building this for production use.

Comment: `<!-- insert "just use boost::variant" comments below -->`

Comment: @H2CO3:  just use boost::variant

Comment: @JohnDibling I saw it coming

Comment: @H2CO3 - Thanks, but it's my task to not use any other libraries

Comment: @Joe in case you didn't notice, I was being sarcastic (I usually do not recommend Boost unless one has a very good reason to use it, and people are often over-using and abusing it and distract beginners from the opportunity of learning by implementing some basic data structures themselves.)

Comment: @H2CO3 - Detecting sarcasm is not my strong point :) - good point though

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/jdibling/core/tree/master/variant) is my attempt at an implementation of a `variant` type class.  Something I wrote a couple years ago for my own amusement.

Comment: Strange things are happening inside your cast function.  Step into that with a debugger.  I have no idea what you are attempting to do there.  cccccccc typically indicates an uninitialized value which is what _n_type is prior to the swap.  When the cast call finishes, _h_ptr is pointing to garbage rather than &'c'.  Is your intent to create memory for the pointer that points to what you want to point to?  If so, you still need to copy something otherwise your new pointer isn't pointing to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps my implementation of the object class will help you. It is similar to `boost::any`, but has a few more features (`operator==` and `operator!=`)

```
class object
{
private:
    class dummy
    {
    public:
        dummy()
        {
        }
        virtual ~dummy()
        {
        }
        virtual const std::type_info &type() const = 0;
        virtual dummy *duplicate() const = 0;
        virtual bool eq(object) = 0;
    };

    template < typename _Ty > class data : public dummy
    {
    public:
        data()
        {
        }

        data(const _Ty &_Value)
            : __data(_Value)
        {
        }

        ~data()
        {
        }

        const std::type_info &type() const
        {
            return typeid(_Ty);
        }

        data *duplicate() const
        {
            return new data<_Ty>(__data);
        }

        bool eq(object _Obj)
        {
            return _Obj.cast<_Ty>() == __data;
        }

        _Ty __data;
    };

    dummy *d;
public:
    object()
    {
    }

    template < typename _Ty > object(const _Ty &_Value)
        : d(new data<_Ty>(_Value))
    {
    }

    object(const object &_Obj)
        : d(_Obj.d->duplicate())
    {
    }

    ~object()
    {
        if (!empty())
        {
            delete d;
        }
    }

    const std::type_info &type() const
    {
        return (empty() ? typeid(void) : d->type());
    }

    object &operator=(object &_Rhs)
    {
        if (&_Rhs != this)
        {
            d = _Rhs.d->duplicate();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    object &swap(object &_Rhs)
    {
        std::swap(*this, _Rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    template < typename _Ty > object &operator=(const _Ty &_Value)
    {
        d = new data<_Ty>(_Value);
        return *this;
    }

    template < typename _Ty > _Ty cast() const
    {
        if (type() == typeid(_Ty))
        {
            return static_cast<data<_Ty> *>(d)->__data;
        }
        throw std::exception("Invalid cast type");
    }

    bool operator==(const object &_Rhs) const
    {
        return (type() == _Rhs.d->type() ? d->eq(_Rhs) : false);
    }

    template < typename _Ty > bool operator==(_Ty _Value) const
    {
        return (type() == typeid(_Ty) ? cast<_Ty>() == _Value : false);
    }

    bool operator!=(const object &_Rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == _Rhs);
    }

    template < typename _Ty > bool operator!=(_Ty _Value) const
    {
        return !(*this == _Value);
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return !d;
    }
};
```

I am afraid just like `boost::any`, there is no getter function, but a `cast` function. It can be used like this

```
int main()
{
    object o = 5;
    object o = (std::string)"Hello\n"; // doesn't like arrays, must be wrapped in a class
    std::cout << o.cast<std::string>().c_str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but your implementation makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. It seems to be based on a completely flawed understanding of memory and the C++ object model, as well as templates. I think in your example program execution, *every* line of `cast` invokes undefined behavior, to the point where it's impossible to say what actually happens.

Throw it away and start again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
template < typename T > struct _base
{
    typedef T _ptr_type;
    _base(_ptr_type value) : _ptr(&value){}
    _ptr_type* _ptr;
};
```

Well, the constructor recieves a `_ptr_type` by value, which means a temporary copy on the stack.  `_ptr(&value)` makes the internal pointer point at this temporary.  Then the constructor returns, and the temporary is destroyed, making this entire class broken.  I'm not sure what the point of this class is yet, so I cannot make suggestions as to how to fix it.

```
struct _holder : _base<void*>
{
    template < typename Ty > void cast(const _base<Ty>* p_base)
    {
        _ptr->~_ptr_type();
        _ptr_type _n_type = (_ptr_type)p_base->_ptr, *_n_ptr = &_n_type;
        std::swap<_ptr_type*>(_ptr, _n_ptr);
    }
};
```

I don't know what this is for either, but the first step of your cast is to destroy the data.  That's... probably a bad idea.  Then you point `_n_type` at the data of `p_base`, and then make `this->_ptr` point at the temporary `_n_type` pointer which is on the stack, which means that when the function ends, `this->_ptr` points at invalid data again.

I have no idea how you thought this was supposed to work, so here's a rundown of the normal interface for this sort of thing:

```
struct object
{
private:
    //base is a non-template, pure virtual interface
    //used to store and access all internal data
    //without knowing the actual type
    struct _interface //not a template
    {
        virtual ~_interface () =0 {};
        //clone allows us to copy without knowing the type
        virtual std::unique_ptr<_interface> clone() const = 0 {} 
    };

    //this actually stores the data
    //it may be given other members, but using these
    //members requires `object` to know the type
    template< typename T>
    struct data: _interface 
    {
        //data() : _data() {} //default constructor - not used
        //data(const data& rhs) : _data(rhs._data) {} //copy constructor - not used
        //data(data&& rhs) : _data(std::move(rhs._data)) {} //move constructor - not used
        data(const T& rhs) : _data(rhs) {} //value by copy
        data(T&& rhs) : _data(std::move(rhs)) {} //value by move
        template< typename... Us> 
        data(Us&&...vs) : _data(std::forward<Us>(vs)...) {} //emplace constructor

        std::unique_ptr<_interface> clone() const //virtual cloning mechanism
        {return std::unique_ptr<data>(new T(_data));}

        T _data;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<_interface> _ptr;
public:    
    object()  //default constructor
    : _ptr() {}
    object(const object&& rhs)  //copy constructor
    : _ptr(rhs ? rhs._ptr->clone() : {}) {}
    object(object&& rhs)  //move constructor
    : _ptr(std::move(rhs._ptr)) {}
    template < typename U> object(const U& _Value) //value by copy
    : _ptr(new data<U>(_Value)) {}
    template < typename U> object(U&& _Value) //value by move
    : _ptr(new data<U>(std::move(_Value)) {}

    object& operator=(const object& rhs) //copy assignment
    {_ptr = rhs ? rhs._ptr->clone() : {}; return *this;}
    object& operator=(object&& rhs) //move assignment
    {_ptr = std::move(rhs._ptr); return *this;}

    //*_ptr gives you a _interface&
    //dynamic_cast<data<T>&> gives you a _data<T>& or throws a std::bad_cast
    //._data gives the actual value
    template< typename T> T& get() 
    {return dynamic_cast<data<T>&>(*_ptr)._data;}
    template< typename T> const T& get() const
    {return dynamic_cast<const data<T>&>(*_ptr)._data;}

    explicit operator bool() const {return _ptr;} //object o; if (o) then ....
};
```

This only handles bare basics.  Everything else is left up to you.